# Why do i need Scala compiler at runtime? (Play2/Salat with Scalap dependency)

Tags: scala, playframework, salat, scalap

I'm using Scala / Mongo / Casbah / Salat / Play2 and when i try to use Salat it seems it has a dependency to Scalap.

It works fine when running the application with `play run` but with `play start` i get the following stack:

```
[info] application - Can't create user 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/util/ClassPath$JavaContext
    at scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigParser$.scalaSigFromAttribute(ScalaSig.scala:35) ~[scalap-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigParser$.parse(ScalaSig.scala:38) ~[scalap-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.novus.salat.util.ScalaSigUtil$$anonfun$parseScalaSig0$2.apply(ScalaSigUtil.scala:73) ~[salat-util_2.9.1-0.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.novus.salat.util.ScalaSigUtil$$anonfun$parseScalaSig0$2.apply(ScalaSigUtil.scala:73) ~[salat-util_2.9.1-0.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at com.novus.salat.util.ScalaSigUtil$.parseScalaSig0(ScalaSigUtil.scala:73) ~[salat-util_2.9.1-0.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.tools.nsc.util.ClassPath$JavaContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
```

`scala/tools/nsc/util/ClassPath$JavaContext` is in the Scala compiler project so i added the SBT dependency:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.1"
```

Now it works fine with `play start` too.

**But is it normal to have to run my project with a runtime dependency to the scala compiler?**
And why does it work with `play run` without the scala compiler dependency? Is it automatically embedded when not running in production mode?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError => ClassPath$JavaContext when using play start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819518/noclassdeffounderror-classpathjavacontext-when-using-play-start)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually Scalap depends on the Scala compiler:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.RC4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/org/scala-lang/scalap/2.9.0.RC4/scalap-2.9.0.RC4.pom

I was having the problem because temporary my dependencies were handled manually and not by SBT.

Now i manage them by SBT and it works fine... but the compiler is still retrieved as a transitive dependency with Salat as initial dependency...

It's strange to have the compiler at runtime but it works...

Answer (score 3):

This happens for two reasons:

- If you are working in dev mode, your classes are continuosly recompiled. So you need a compiler.
- If you use the stage mode, the classes are compiled once forever, but this is done internally . If not you would have to provide a reference to the scala compiler, which could replace the scala compiler dependency.

Comment: Ok so it should explain why it works fine with play run, but actually with play start i'm in production mode, everything is compiler before so why would i need a compiler dependency?

Comment: Like it's described here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Production With start or stage the result is the same

Comment: Actually the play server compiles well, starts well. It's only when using Salat, which is using Scalap, that a get the following stack. Isn't Scalap usable at runtime? Isn't Scala compiler supposed to not be in the runtime? Thus why make such a dependency?

Comment: Scalap depends on Scala compiler.